# Different keys for the bastion and ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I have a bastion server on AWS which I connect to through the following configuration:

```
host bastion
Hostname <bastion_public_ip>
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
User ubuntu
```

Now, I have setup an instance where this bastion is used as a jump server. However, the instance is created with a separate key `mykey.pem` and not the SSH key used to connect to the bastion. Earlier, when I was using the same key, I could connect with the following config:

```
host test-ec2
hostname <ec2_private_ip>
IdentityFile .ssh/id_rsa
User ec2-user
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p bastion
```

However, now when I change the identity file to `~/mykey.pem`, this does not work anymore. I wonder how I can set this up to use different keys and pass that through this SSH proxy command.

Comment: Usually you would `scp` the key to bastion. But today you would just use aws ssm session manager.

Comment: Yeah, but usually it says we should not have private keys on the bastion. I wonder if there is a `ssh` only option.

Comment: I agree with @Marcin -- Using SSH and a Bastion server is somewhat outdated. Instead, the [AWS Systems Manager Session](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html) Manager allows you to connect to an EC2 instance even if it is in a Private Subnet. This is possible because the instance creates an _outbound_ connection to AWS. It can also use IAM permissions instead of keypairs and access is logged in CloudTrail.

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate a public key for the key you want to use. You can do this by using tools like PuTTYgen.
2. Copy the public key and ssh into your jump host (using mykey.pem (new key) )
3. run the following command `vi .ssh/authorized_keys` hit "i" to edit file and paste the public key you have copied (don't delete the existing public key in that file if you still need to access the jump host using new pem file) now hit escape and :wq and hit enter to save the file.
4. Now exit the jump host and try to ssh again with your old key which you have created public key.

Comment: 4. Now exit the jump host and try to ssh again with your old key which you have created public key.

Answer (score 0):

This config should work for `ssh test-ec2`:

```
Host bastion
  HostName     <bastion_public_ip>
  User         ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host test-ec2
  HostName     <ec2_private_ip>
  User         ec2-user
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey.pem
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p bastion
```

For newer version of OpenSSH, `ProxyCommand` can be replaced with the following line:

```
  ProxyJump bastion
```